# I am trying to make a use system for my discord bot (py), but it does not work

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am trying to make an economy system for my discord servers with `discord.py` but I cannot find any system to use an object which is stored in an inventory in `.JSON`. I would like that when we call the function use, for example, it removes an object from my inventory, and if this object is not in my inventory, it tells me that I do not have it.

My code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def use(ctx, item, amount = -1,):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    res = await use_this(ctx.author,item,amount)

    if item <= 0 in 

    if not res[0]:
        if res[1]==1:
            await ctx.send("That Object isn't there!")
            return
        if res[1]==2:
            await ctx.send(f"Vous n'avez pas cette objet{amount} {item}")
            return

    await ctx.send(f"You use 1 {item}")

async def use_this(user,item_name,amount):
    item_name = item_name.lower()
    name_ = None
    for item in mainshop:
        name = item["name"].lower()
        if name == item_name:
            name_ = name
            price = item["price"]
            break

    if name_ == None:
        return [False,1]

    cost = price*amount

    users = await get_bank_data()

    bal = await update_bank(user)

    if bal[0]<cost:
        return [False,2]


    try:
        index = 0
        t = None
        for thing in users[str(user.id)]["inv"]:
            n = thing["item"]
            if n == item_name:
                old_amt = thing["amount"]
                new_amt = old_amt + amount
                users[str(user.id)]["inv"][index]["amount"] = new_amt
                t = 1
                break
            index+=1 
        if t == None:
            obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
            users[str(user.id)]["inv"].append(obj)
    except:
        obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
        users[str(user.id)]["inv"] = [obj]        

    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    return [True,"Worked"]
```

Comment: I think what you want is a database. If you only want to store data in JSON, then I'd look into firebase.

Comment: ok thank you I will go find out about Firebase

Comment: is ‘JSON.loads’ what you’re looking for?